# what could be the reason that my ember application works fine when connected to safari's debugging console but not otherwise

Tags: ios, safari, ember.js

I am observing a strange behavior in my ember application on iOS devices.

When the device is connected to the debugging console (by using the develop menu and selecting the device/the web page), everything works well, but when the device is not connected, the screen doesn't properly refresh. Clicking on content which updates some portion of the screen, leaves it blank.

Any lead, hint would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Wild guess: could be a concurrency issue, and the debugger slows the execution down just enough so that whatever needs to run before, runs.

Comment: Yes, it is likely a concurrency issue. Make sure when you are processing data that you are waiting for it to be loaded first.

Comment: do you have any recommendations i should go on to find out the culprit(s)… the console is not much help :)

Comment: i was able to catch an error on the console regarding partials - "TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'partials.waitPartialView')" - but i don't get that error on my computer, just on the iOS devices.

Comment: i have solved the issue by not using partial views… not ideal, but i could move forward.